# Retrieve friend lit from jon decoded array

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

what i want to do is to display a list of friends and their images in ul li format on a webpage,
I have json decoded string array that contains user information in it. Ho do i do it with PHP?

```
object(stdClass)#4 (4){["entries"]=>array(3){[0]=>object(stdClass)#5 (10){["uid"]=>float(1.5555133825854E+14)["photo"]=>string(90) "https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-prn1/323887_155551338258538_1152153357_q.jpg"["type"]=>string(4) "user"["text"]=>string(13) "shikhadamodar"["path"]=>string(17) "/shikha.damodar.1"["category"]=>string(6) "Madiun"["names"]=>array(1){[0]=>string(13) "shikhadamodar"}["index_rank"]=>int(-1)["needs_update"]=>bool(true)["non_title_tokens"]=>string(6) "madiun"}[1]=>object(stdClass)#6 (10){["uid"]=>float(1.5555133217343E+14)["photo"]=>string(90) "https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-snc3/273318_155551332173428_2131571532_q.jpg"["type"]=>string(4) "user"["text"]=>string(14) "shreya damodar"["path"]=>string(14) "/my.devprofile"["category"]=>string(5) "Nilai"["names"]=>array(1){[0]=>string(13) "shreyadamodar"}["index_rank"]=>int(-1)["needs_update"]=>bool(true)["non_title_tokens"]=>string(5) "nilai"}[2]=>object(stdClass)#7 (10){["uid"]=>float(1.5555558723211E+14)["photo"]=>string(83) "https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-prn1/41332_155555587232111_3158_q.jpg"["type"]=>string(4) "user"["text"]=>string(9) "neha neha"["path"]=>string(12) "/neha.neha34"["category"]=>string(18) "New York,New York"["names"]=>array(1){[0]=>string(9) "Neha neha"}["index_rank"]=>int(-1)["needs_update"]=>bool(true)["non_title_tokens"]=>string(18) "new york,new york"}}["token"]=>string(12) "1333551453-7"["display_token"]=>int(5)["display_ttl"]=>int(1333541132)}
```

what is the efficient way to do this??

Comment: json_decode($arr, TRUE) will return it in assoc array format. Perhaps it will be easier for you to use it..

Comment: i tried json_decode($arr) and it works for other answers!
But when adding TRUE to that, it shows an error `"Notice:Trying to get property of non-object in"`
@Svetlio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

Lets consider your json_decoded code is in $arr variable array

```
foreach ($arr->entries as $val) {
    echo "<ul><li>".$val['uid']."</li></ul>";
    //put your li code here
}
```

Something like this

Comment: Upvote needs reputation and flagging needs 9 minute, of course i will do :)

Comment: @sheryadamodar what us idx()?

Comment: echo "<ul><li>".$val['uid']."</li></ul>"; shows an error!!

Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /path/ :)

Comment: idx i function to parse array i use in code!

function idx(array $array, $key, $default = null) {
  return array_key_exists($key, $array) ? $array[$key] : $default;
}
may this helps some!

Comment: Your answer is pretty right! but
foreach ($payload->entries as $val) {
echo "<ul><li>".$val['uid']."</li></ul>";
} this code gives an error!
<br/>
Fatal error:Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ----.php
@Chandresh-cool

Comment: Yes! it worked, but i wonder why i get below float value instead of real UID hen decoding json? json shows real id, not float value.  1.0000135870804E+14 1.0000176737633E+14 1.0000056776239E+14 @chandresh_cool

Comment: I see something kind of float( appended in ur printed result?

Comment: Ya. that's what am now confusing about  :) 
Actually am coding a fb app that shows persons who not yet accepted friend requests!
Just like this one.

http://apps.facebook.com/friendrequests/
@chandresh_cool

Comment: @sheryadamodar I found solution of your problem the UID string is long intger hence json_decode is converting it to scintific notation Use this print_r(json_decode($arr, false,512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($jarr->entries as $val) {
    echo "<ul><li>".$val->uid."</li></ul>";
}
```

Comment: Do you know why i get below float value instead of real UID hen decoding json? json shows real id, not float value.
<br/>
1.0000135870804E+14<br/>
1.0000176737633E+14<br/>
1.0000056776239E+14<br/>
@karmafunk